# How to disable routing in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a single page application that really just has one single page. There's just the one view that has lots of javascript/ajax logic done with angularjs, but there's no routing to other views involved.

Therefore I'd like to git rid of the hashbang (#/) at the end of the url. Can I somehow turn off angularjs routing completely?

Btw: I know about Htm5Mode, but I want it to work in all browsers.

Comment: If you don't have any routes, why did you define routing at all?

Comment: Remove anything related to $routeProvider from your app (config)

Comment: if you know about Html5Mode, its needed when you use routing at all.Just remove all $routeProvider from the app

Comment: I believe I also had to remove $location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a `$routeProvider` defined, there will be no routing, and therefore no hash in your url.

Comment: This is not the case.  Hash urls are modified by angular even if the ng app does not use the router.

Comment: Agreed. It appears that `ng-include` will turn on routing, even when you use no other Angular features.  Are you using `ng-include`?

Comment: @Sharky did you find a way to avoid this behavior when using ng-include? I have a single-page parallax using controllers but not routing, and when using ng-include angular replaces anchor url from this #clients to this #/clients

Comment: I did, but unfortunately, I no longer remember how I did it. But I can tell you for sure that it's possible. I think it had something to do with intercepting functionality in a core Angular service through some form of delegation.

Comment: I believe I also had to remove $location