# Routing in angularJS when project contains jQuery code as well as angularJS code

Tags: jquery, angularjs, route-provider

I have a project with one file one.html and another file two.html. File one.html works with jquery and is bound to root ("/") and two.html works with angularJS and the route is "/two.html#/partialtemplate".

What can I do to remove "/two.html#" from the route? I don't want this to show in the URL.

I have tried $locationProvider.html5mode(true) but it didn't work because the base URL("/one.html") is already bound to one.html.

Comment: You would need to combine both pages functionality into one `index.html` to do what you are asking. With 2 files server wouldn't know which one to send the way you are suggesting. Explanation of your current configuration is a little bit unclear

Comment: Alternative would be 2 index.html...each in different directory then let server send index based on directory in url

Comment: thanks @charlietfl I used some of your pointers to provide a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Sol:

Do not load the `$routeProvider` by removing the ui router file form the index page where you dont want routing

Some references:
1) [Disable angularJs routing, routeprovider already gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379715/disable-angularjs-routing-routeprovider-already-gone)

2) [How to disable routing in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780559/how-to-disable-routing-in-angularjs)